# Shared folders are not listed in "net share"

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, shared-folders, sharing

I dont understand why there are not shared folders when I use "net share" I also tried "net view" and "net use" but nothing. Any ideas ? I googled the problem but could not find anything.

Nothing in the CMD:

[image]

But the folders are connected and I can access them.
[image]

Comment: I think there is a difference between shared drives that your computer sees, and network drives you have actually connected to your computer. Net use will show remote shared you have made "persistent" on your computer, I believe. How did you connect these network drives?

Comment: I simply right click in my computer and chose add a network location then put the ip address there and chose the folder

Comment: Use Net Use to add a network drive, and then see if it shows in the list you expect. There is a difference between Explorer remembering you've visited a network location, and your computer having a defined network drive.